# C++ error: 'operator=' is a private member of 'std::__1::thread'

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm using Eclipse Neon and trying to create a basic example of concurrent counters that increment and decrement by 20, but the build won't compile.  Two lines of my code are being highlighted and both are showing the following error:

'operator=' is a private member of 'std::__1::thread'

The lines in question are:

```
upThreads[i] = std::thread(increment20);
downThreads[i] = std::thread(decrement20);
```

The full code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

std::mutex mymutex;
int counter;

void increment20() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mymutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        ++counter;
    }
}

void decrement20() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mymutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        --counter;
    }
}

int main() {

    std::thread upThreads[10];
    std::thread downThreads[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        upThreads[i] = std::thread(increment20);
        downThreads[i] = std::thread(decrement20);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        upThreads[i].join();
        downThreads[i].join();
    }

    std::cout << "final value: " << counter << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There should be no problems with those lines, since they should be using the move assignment operator instead of the copy assignment operator. What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: They're move assignable.

Comment: As mentioned above, your problem is [not reproducible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eda4427c05800cc6). Which compiler options are you using?

Comment: I'm a complete beginner with C++, so sorry if I'm not relaying back the correct info here.  I'm not sure how to see the C++ version in Eclipse.  But the toolchain is Cross GCC and the builder is Gnu Make Builder.

Comment: Can it be that you haven't tried to build it just the Eclipse IDE tells you what it thinks about your code? Eclipse is written by Java programmers and those can't parse C++ too well.

Comment: I found the problem, thank you @BenjaminLindley and Rakete1111 for calling out the settings.  If anyone comes across this issue, I found the setting for C++ version in the Dialect settings.  Right click on the project and follow this path:  Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Dialect

Answer (score 2):

Answer found to be the C++ version settings in Eclipse.  Right click on the project and follow this path through settings:

Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Dialect

then select ISO C11 in the Language standard field.

Make sure to change the setting for whichever compiler is being used, or set it for all the compilers.

Answer (score 2):

On MAC use command line with `-std=c++11` option passed, like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 thread_test.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: There are other circumstances under which you can get the same error message:

In particular, I got this message when I accidentally swapped the parameter order of the constructor, passing "this" as the first parameter (where the function pointer should go) instead of as the first parameter *after* the function pointer.